# Is there any way to select all images of a certain size in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, css-selectors, getelementsbytagname

I want to select all the images on a webpage bigger than a certain size, say 200 x 200 pixels. Is there any way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: yes, inspect all image tags for the image dimensions

Comment: @JaromandaX That will tell you the size the image is being rendered within, but not necessarily the native image size.

Comment: 1) Wait for all images to finish loading. 2) Find all the `<img>` elements. 3) Filter that collection based on the image dimensions using the `naturalWidth` / `naturalHeight` properties

Comment: @ScottMarcus - depends on what you do ... when I said inspect all tags, I didn't mean inspect the img tag attributes - I meant, gte all `img` ... then use the correct methods to access the native image size - basically exactly what is in the answer by someone below

Comment: @JaromandaX And what methods would you call to get the native image size?

Comment: @ScottMarcus - the correct ones - the OP wrote zero code, so I made a suggestion with zero code - seems only fair - Phil seemed to give pseudo code, and that is way more effort than the OP

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not even sure how OP intends to filter the images. What needs to be compared? Is it any dimension over a certain threshold or should it compare total image area in px^2?

Comment: @Phil - yeah, is the criteria any dimension over 200, both dimensions over 200, total area over 40000 ... but still - vague question, with absolutely no research effort, at best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll('img'),
  len = img.length,
  counter = 0;

[].forEach.call(img, function(img) {
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    counter++;
    if (counter === len) {
      console.log('all images loaded at ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
      check(); // call automatically without user interaction
    }
  }, false);
});

check(); // just to show it works only after all image loads

function check(size) {
  if (counter !== len) {
    console.log('waiting for images to load at ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    return;
  }
  let result = {};
  img.forEach(e => {
    if (!result[e.naturalHeight + 'x' + e.naturalWidth]) {
      result[e.naturalHeight + 'x' + e.naturalWidth] = [];
    }
    if (size && e.naturalHeight >= size && e.naturalWidth >= size) {
      result[e.naturalHeight + 'x' + e.naturalWidth].push(e.src);
    } else if (typeof(size) == 'undefined') {
      result[e.naturalHeight + 'x' + e.naturalWidth].push(e.src);
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="check()">Check Size</button>
<button onclick="check(600)">Check Size > 600</button>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" />
</div>
```

Comment: You should make sure the images are completely loaded before attempting to get their dimensions

Comment: Also, I didn't downvote but this won't help OP find images over a certain size

Comment: have edited the post. OP has not said when the function is to be triggered.

Comment: What I mean is that at the very minimum, you need to wait for images to load before you execute filtering. If I click your button before the images load, it gives bad results.

Comment: yes, of course, you are correct. I did think that way, but OP has not mentioned any, but let me just do something around that scenario as well. Thanks @Phil

Comment: @Phil have edited the answer accordingly. Checks the  image, call the function after all images are loaded....